# Problem with or in Regexp

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, pcre

I have this Regexp:

```
/\{%\s([^else|endloop|endif][a-z0-9\.\|_]+)\s%\}/si
```

I use this regexp in preg_replace.
And this markup:

```
{# comment %}

{# comment number 2$% %}

{% variable %}

{% array.key1.key2 %}

{% array.key1.key2|escape|bold %}

{% variable|escape %}

{% loop array as item %}
    My item is {% item.text %}
{% endloop %}

{% if (something): %}
    do something truly
{% else: %}
    nothing to do
{% endif; %}
```

Why this regexp is not working for `{% item.text %}` but works with other?
I think that I made some mistake here `[^else|endloop|endif]`

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: In my regex tester it's matched items 3 to 6. Any improvement if you used '/\\{%\\s([^else|endloop|endif][a-z0-9\\.\\|_]+)\\s%\\}/si'

Comment: Try this - http://www.functions-online.com/preg_replace.html and set $replacement to $1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you may intend:

```
/\{%\s((?!(else|endloop|endif))[a-z0-9\.\|_]+)\s%\}/si
```

The square brackets previously containing the `else`, `endloop` and `endif` keywords treats each individual character as an exception. Here they are treated as whole strings.